# MySQL query returns null results when used in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting null results when I use the following Like query in PHP Script

```
    $MasjidName = $_GET['MasjidName'];
$Percent = "%";
$search = $Percent.$MasjidName.$Percent;

echo $search;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `MasjidMaster` WHERE `MasjidName` LIKE '".$search."'";

// get a product from products table
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

I have tried the following too

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `MasjidMaster` WHERE `MasjidName` LIKE '%moh%'") or die(mysql_error());
```

The following is the null result I have been getting

```
{"masjids":[{"MasjidName":null,"Address":null,"Latitude":null,"Longitude":null}],"success":1,"masjid":[]}
```

whole code added below the following is the script i have been trying to get work

```
   <?php
    $response = array();
    require_once dirname(__FILE__ ). '/db_connect.php';;
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();
    if (isset($_GET["MasjidName"])) 
    {
            $MasjidName = $_GET['MasjidName'];
            $MasjidName = mysql_real_escape_string($MasjidName);  // you have to escape your variable here.
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `MasjidMaster` WHERE `MasjidName` LIKE '%$MasjidName%'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            $response["masjids"] = array();

        if (!empty($result)) {
            // check for empty result
            if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {


                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

                $masjid = array();
                $masjid["MasjidName"] = $row["MasjidName"];
                $masjid["Address"] = $row["Address"];
                $masjid["Latitude"] = $row["Latitude"];
                $masjid["Longitude"] = $row["Longitude"];

                // success
                $response["success"] = 1;

                // user node
                $response["masjid"] = array();
                array_push($response["masjids"], $masjid);

                }
                // echoing JSON response
                echo json_encode($response);
            } else {
                // no product found
                $response["success"] = 0;
                $response["message"] = "No product found";

                // echo no users JSON
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        } else {
            // no product found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No product found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // required field is missing
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Does it work fine without the WHERE clause?

Comment: please print here what result is coming for `SELECT * FROM MasjidMaster WHERE MasjidName`

Comment: 1) Start by not using `mysql`. Use `mysqli` or `PDO`. 2) Your code isn't secure. Anyone can inject your query. 3) Maybe there are no records to that condition. try using `num_rows` - if it's `0` there are no results and your query is fine.

Comment: Duplicate `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948102/mysql-like-query-fails-in-php.`  :)

Comment: @michael I have tried it without the WHERE clause,it does return results when there is no Where Clause . I have tested the Like query in MySQL too it does return results there too .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$MasjidName = $_GET['MasjidName'];
$MasjidName = mysql_real_escape_string($MasjidName);  // you have to escape your variable here.
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `MasjidMaster` WHERE `MasjidName` LIKE '%$MasjidName%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: what didnt work ? some error messages ? can you provide full code and your sample data from your table ? . this code i gave you is very simple and should work.

Comment: added script please recheck

Comment: remove that line  `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);`

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM MasjidMaster WHERE MasjidName LIKE '".$search."'";
```

I tried `SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City LIKE 's%';` and it gave me perfectly fine result. But when i tried `SELECT * FROM 'Customers' WHERE 'City' LIKE 's%';` it gave me a null result.

Just remove `''` and give it a try. Hope it helps.